# How to save/insert non english document in mongodb through mongo shell command prompt

Tags: mongodb

Example: I want to save something like this.

```
db.collectionname.insert([
{
    Language:"Tamil",
    Chapter:"CHP1",
    Questions:[
            {
                Question: "ஒரு மின்காந்த அலை ஒரு ஊடகத்தின் வழியே □(→┬V )=Vi ̂ திசைவேகத்தில் பரவுகிறது. அந்த கனத்தில் மின்காந்த அலையின் மின்புலம் +y அச்சில் அலைவுறுகிறது எனில் , அலைவுறும் காந்தபுலத்தின் திசை ",
                Answer: [
                    "+Z திசையில்"
                    "-y திசையில்",
                    "-Z திசையில்",
                    "-x திசையில் "
                ],
                CorrectAnswer: "-x திசையில் ",
                Explanation:"-x திசையில் "
            }
        ]
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a comma in your `Answer` array, the following works:

```
db.collectionname.insert([
{
    Language:"Tamil",
    Chapter:"CHP1",
    Questions:[
            {
                Question: "ஒரு மின்காந்த அலை ஒரு ஊடகத்தின் வழியே □(→┬V )=Vi ̂ திசைவேகத்தில் பரவுகிறது. அந்த கனத்தில் மின்காந்த அலையின் மின்புலம் +y அச்சில் அலைவுறுகிறது எனில் , அலைவுறும் காந்தபுலத்தின் திசை ",
                Answer: [
                    "+Z திசையில்",
                    "-y திசையில்",
                    "-Z திசையில்",
                    "-x திசையில் "
                ],
                CorrectAnswer: "-x திசையில் ",
                Explanation:"-x திசையில் "
            }
        ]
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks dnickless. Its working. Note: If I fetch the data in mongo shell after insertion, the documents are displayed as "??????" (i.e Question marks). But if I retrieve the data using mongoose and display in UI, it showing the actual information/data.

Comment: @AshokK, that behaviour is caused by your console window rather than the mongo client. See this for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line/15858812